# Do these Lagrange equations of 1st kind exhibit numerical instabilities?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, computational-physics, constrained-dynamics, non-linear-systems

I followed the lead of "Theoretische Physik", 1e, 2015 by Bartelmann et al. (pp. 171 - 174) to form the set of constituting Lagrange equations of the 1st kind for the double pendulum: eight 1st order ODEs of the form

$$ \dot{x} = f(x, \lambda(x)), $$

where $x$ are states, and $\lambda$ are lagrange multipliers.

The defining equations for the lagrange multipliers are

$$
\sum_{i=1}^{2N} \frac{1}{m_i} \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial x_i} \sum_{b=1}^r \lambda_b \frac{\partial f_b}{\partial x_i} = g_a - \sum_{i=1}^{2N}\frac{1}{m_i} \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial x_i} F_i, \; \; a = 1..n
$$

where $n$ is the number of constraints, $N$ is the number of mass points, $f_a$ are the (holonomic) constraints, and $g_a$ are terms obtained from taking the $2^{\text{nd}}$ total time derivative of the constraints:

$$
0 = \ddot{f_a} = \sum_{i=1}^{2N} \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial x_i} \ddot{x_i} - g_a(t, x, \dot{x}).
$$

Dynamics are then computed using

$$
m_i \ddot{x}_i = \sum_{a=1}^{r} \lambda_a \frac{\partial f_a}{\partial x_i} + F_i, \; \; i = 1..2N.
$$

I observed the following:

While the integration of the mass points' ODEs yielded plausible results, the two masses were slightly off the constraints of circular motion about the pivot points which I stated as constraints.

Given my equations are right, could approximation errors in the ODE solver, or the linear equations involving the lagrange multipliers, be the cause of the non-circular motion? Could the constraints being considered only as second deriatives over time be the reason?

---

The constraints are as follows:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_1 & = & x_1^2 + y_1^2 - (l_1/2)^2 = 0 \\
f_2 & = & (x_2 - 2x_1)^2 + (y_2 - 2y_1)^2 - (l_2/2)^2 = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

They state that mass $m_1$ is on a circle about $(0, 0)$ with radius $l_1/2$, and that mass $m_2$ is on a circle about the joint at position $(2x_1, 2x_2)$ with radius $l_2/2$.

The intial conditions are

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x_0 & = & (x_{10}, \; \dot{x}_{10}, \; y_{10}, \; \dot{y}_{10}, \; x_{20}, \; \dot{x}_{20}, \; y_{20}, \; \dot{y}_{20}) \\
& = & (0, \; 0, \; -l_1/2, \; 0, \; l_2/2, \; 0, \; -l_1, \; 0),
\end{eqnarray}
$$

which are consistent with the constraints.

The below given trajectory of $m_1$ in the $(x, y)$ plane shows that $m_1$ is off the circle about $(0, 0)$. For completeness, a time series plot of $m_1$'s $x$- and $y$-coordinates are shown.

Parameters for integration are $l_1 = l_2 = m_1 = m_2 = g = 1$.

[image]

---

Strangely, a similar drifting effect occurs when the movement of the two masses is constrained by the following set of equations. They represent a crossbar movement of point masses where mass $1$ moves horizontally, mass $2$ moves vertically, and both masses are connected by a rigid rod of length $L$:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
f_1 & = & x_1^2 + y_2^2 - L^2 = 0 \\
f_2 & = & x_2 = 0 \\
f_3 & = & y_1 = 0
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Again, the initial conditions are consistent with the constraints:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x_0 & = & (x_{10}, \; \dot{x}_{10}, \; y_{10}, \; \dot{y}_{10}, \; x_{20}, \; \dot{x}_{20}, \; y_{20}, \; \dot{y}_{20}) \\
& = & (-L, \; 0, \; 0, \; 0, \; 0, \; 0, \; 0, \; 0).
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Below is a plot showing the change of the length of the rod over time which clearly violates the first constraint $f_1$:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, integration of the crossbar system with Runge-Kutta scheme of order 4 and 5 does result in numerical instabilities. One can tell by removing the constant states $x_2$ and $y_1$ (and its timely derivatives) from the set of ordinary differential equations. Integrating the reduced system

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
m_1 \ddot{x}_1 & = & - \frac{\dot{x}_1^2 + \dot{y}_2^2 - y_2g}{x_1^2/m_1 + y_2^2/m_2}x_1, \\
m_2 \ddot{y}_2 & = & - \frac{\dot{x}_1^2 + \dot{y}_2^2 - y_2g}{x_1^2/m_1 + y_2^2/m_2}y_2 - m_2 g,
\end{eqnarray}
$$

with $\textbf{x}_0 = (-L, \; 0, \; 0, \; 0)$, and $m_1 = m_2 = g = L = 1$ makes a better approximation, but still violates constraint $f_1$ (blue: full order system, orange: reduced order system):

[image]

Important to note that the choice of the integration method `Radau` reduced the error an order of magnitude of 3:

[image]

This is surprising, since the two masses oscillate with the same frequency. Hence, no stiff behavior and no need for a stiff solver.

As for the double pendulum system, it is clear that the full set of eight ordinary differential equations somehow *overdetermines* the dynamics, since only four are required (two angles and angular velocities).

But it is still an open question to me what exactly goes wrong here.